# How to install OpenContrail without OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, sdn, openstack-neutron

I want to understand what magic can OpenContrail do as Software Defined Networking and I am new to this OpenContrail Concept and VMs, etc. To understand this, I just want to install OpenContrail on my Ubuntu VM. I tried to follow this [Official quick Start Guide](http://www.opencontrail.org/opencontrail-quick-start-guide/). But. It looks It installs OpenStack Components also when I invoke fabric Scripts.

Is it mandatory to use OpenStack to understand the magic of OpenContrail.? If Yes, Why is it so.?

Thanks,

Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a simpler set of instructions and use docker containers:
http://www.opencontrail.org/docker-with-opencontrail/

There is also work going on in order to be able to provision opencontrail with kubernetes as a cluster management system. Reach out in the #opencontrail channel on freenode.net if you want to try one of these options.